# consume c# array of structs using c++ unmanaged Dll

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, struct

as i am new to the `unmanaged` world, and after a success test of interacting with `c++ DLL` on a simple task, 
i am now trying to consume in `c#`, data manipulated by `c++` via an `array` of `struct`

i have also tried to wrap the struct[] within another struct to simplify the marshal but i did not succeed in any way.

what is the correct (and most efficient performance wise)  way to handle the data returned from c++ given the code below.

**C#**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct chars
{
    public int V;
    //[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public char[] testStr;
}

       [DllImport("ExportStructArr.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern void dodata(int requestedMasterArrLength, int requestedStringSize,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out()] chars[] Cars);

//tried also this signature 
        public static extern void dodata(
                        int requestedMasterArrLength,
                        int requestedStringSize,
                        out IntPtr chars);
```

**c++**

```
#ifdef EXPORTSTRUCTARR_EXPORTS
#define EXPORTSTRUCTARR_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
typedef struct {
    int Id;
    char *StrVal;
}Unit;


EXPORTSTRUCTARR_API  void dodata(int requestedMasterArrLength,int requestedStringSize, Unit **UntArr)
{

    int ccountr,count;
    count=0;


     *UntArr = (Unit*)LocalAlloc(0, requestedMasterArrLength * sizeof(Unit));
     Unit *CurU = *UntArr;
    while(count!= requestedMasterArrLength)
    {
        char dummyStringDataObject[]= "abcdefgHi";
        CurU[count].StrVal = NULL;

        dummyStringDataObject[0] = count+'0';
        CurU[count].Id = count;


        CurU[count].StrVal= (char*) LocalAlloc(0,(sizeof(char)* requestedStringSize));
        ccountr=0;
        while(ccountr!= requestedStringSize){
            CurU[count].StrVal[ccountr] = dummyStringDataObject[ccountr];
            ++ccountr;
        }
         ++count;

    }


}
```

Comment: This is as inefficient as you could possibly make it.  Fake code again, you can't get useful answers when the code is nonsense.

Comment: this question is NOT about 'c', so please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: @HansPassant , hey sorry about all the mess. i did manage to process the return data, so i am now actually done solving this qusetion, although there is an issue with the char[] or say string , as i return the array of the structs, i need to iterate on the struct array and on each struct i need to manipulate the memory somehow to build a string , so the process of travelling to the unmanaged world, processing fast , though returning and needing the reverse actions... no speed gained here... i need to see how i can make sense managing data in unmanaged is efficient.

Comment: @HansPassant the concept is storing data in a fast collection, so maybe, i should leave the values of the string for later when asked for, so than i can leave out the processing of the string , though i cant leave the extraction of the string for later cause it could get overwritten, i need to re think the logic again..

Comment: Collections are the one feature where C# always consistently beats C++.  They are hard to do efficiently without a garbage collector.